# C# Async sockets dont return the full page

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

This is my create socket part:

```
_client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_client.BeginConnect(_IPEnd, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), _client);
connectDone.WaitOne();
Send(_client, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.de\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n");
```

The recv part:

```
private void Receive()
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = _client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        _client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length , 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,state.buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else 
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead)); 
            int length = state.sb.ToString().Length;
            ProcessData(state.sb.ToString());

            receiveDone.Set();
        }

    }
```

The Buffer

```
    public class StateObject
    {
        private Guid ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 4096;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

Why is this code not returning the full page?

Is there something wrong with this part in recvcallback

```
if (bytesRead > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be *assuming* that you will only be called back when *either* the buffer is full *or* the connection has been closed. That's simply not the case. You could have an 8K buffer, and 20K of data being sent from the server, which is read as 2K in each of 10 calls.

Assuming you want to read until the connection is closed, you should keep going until `client.EndReceive` returns 0. (For HTTP with keepalive, you'd need to read the content length and keep going until you'd read that much data in the body.)

EDIT: I've just seen you've set Keep-Alive on the connection. Don't do that if you want the server to close the connection to tell you it's finished!

(In general, it's much better to use an HTTP library for all of this, of course - why are you writing your own HTTP-handling code?)

Comment: @jeb: Well it's definite better - but you obviously don't need the `Append` call if you haven't received any data...

Comment: hello, my code is only working when i step through the code, step by step, then it return 28000 in length, but if i run it normal it just gets 4000 in length
Do you know why?

Comment: @jeb: Yes - when you run as normal, you're reading data as quickly as it's arriving. When you're stepping through, it's all arrived by the time you get to the receive call, because of the manual steps involved.

Comment: How can i fix that? so the async code works? what is wrong? 
I tried this all the day already, would be nice if you can tell me

Comment: @jeb: Ah, so it's only returning 4000 characters *in total* when you run normally? Put some diagnostics in showing how many bytes are being read in each EndReceive call.

Comment: Hey i logged the bytesread value: 
1.4096
2.4096
3.4096
4.4096
5.4096
6.4096
7.4096
8.835
After this 8. call the else case is not called, the socket isnt responding anymore why

Comment: @jeb: So it's getting all the data, which is fine - but then not disconnecting. Ah - I've just seen that you've set Keep-alive on the connection. That's the problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Its because i want to make an autologin tool for some site and its alot faster to do that multithreaded with asyncsockets, then the WebClasses, i took out the Keep-Alive, but it doesnt return back to the else block why?
Edit: with connection close in the Get it works perfect :)

Comment: @jeb: Faster than `WebRequest.BeginGetResponse` etc? There are ways to get asynchronous web handling without writing your own HTTP stack...

Comment: jon you are right i think; WebRequest.BeginGetResponse looks much easier

Answer (score 0):

Check your buffer length. Probably is much shorter than the effective page length. So, you must accumulate the chunks received on another buffer, then retrigger the BeginReceive until the data length is zero.

Comment: So when the page is 20k bytes do i have to set my buffer to a size of 20000?

Comment: No, that would be a bad way to solve the problem. Your block buffer should be 4096 bytes, for instance. Then your socket will call you back once a block is full, or the whole stream is over. Every received block has to be appended into another (I'd say) stream, that's the resulting file. However, as Jon observed, you must keep the connection open during the download of the blocks.